# HTML GIF/Animation enable/start on scroll?

Tags: html, animation, scroll, gif

im looking for help on how to make a gif or some sort of animation start or begin when the user scroll beyond a certain point.

Like on the apple website you can see the animation of the little web elements when you scroll though the page. (ex. the dimensions of the device, download speeds )
http://www.apple.com/iphone/features/

or here on the blackmagic website:
http://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/blackmagicpocketcinemacamera/design/

Im not sure if using a gif would work best or what other options to go with.

Any advice on how to go about something like this?

Thanks

Schoolpost,

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) is a great jQuery plugin to fire custom events when the page is scrolled to a certain vertical point in a certain direction (up or down).

Comment: That's perfect! Exactly what I was looking for and it's very simple. One thing to note that took some time to figure out: place the waypoint script at the end of the document or it won't work (at least for me).